# Javascript increment number between square brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, increment

This is my text input box

```
<input class="tb" id="tb43[0]" type="text" size="30" maxlength="200" />
```

When cloning with jQuery I'd like the id of the new cloned box to be **"tb43[1]"**.

```
$clone.find(".tb").attr("id").replace(/\d+/, function (val) { return parseInt(val) + 1; });
```

This only increments the first number but how can I manage to increment the number in the square brackets?

Thanks

Comment: if you are posting to a php script, using `[]` is usually sufficient, it will be incremented internally.

Comment: If you have to do something like this it is good to rethink the architecture and maybe try a different aproach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You can use `.attr("id", function() {})` to change the ID. You're currently not altering the ID.
2. You can alter the regexp to match only in square brackets.
3. You can use `+` instead of `parseInt` (the latter has some caveats).

E.g.

```
$clone.find(".tb").attr("id", function(i, id) {
  return id.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function(match, number) {
    // `number` refers to the first group (denoted with ())
    return "[" + (+number + 1) + "]";
  })
});
```

Comment: that helped a lot. I slightly modified your solution in a separate function:
function incrementBracketValue(str)
{
 var incrementedValue = parseInt(str.match(/\[(\d+)\]/)[1])+1;
 return str.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, "["+incrementedValue+"]")
}

Comment: @dalars27, you might like to accept pimvdb's answer as correct by clicking the green tick, under the voting controls to the left of the answer.

Comment: @dalars27: Do please use `+` instead of `parseInt` because you could get weird results otherwise (`parseInt("080") === 0`). And you need to escape the square brackets.

Comment: @pimvdb worked on my code again after your advice, thx - I learnt quite a lot today

Comment: @pimvdb GREATNESS. Scoured the net to find this solution. Helping me add repeater fields with multi array posting.

Comment: @Foxinni: Well, you're lucky you didn't search before yesterday, then :)

Comment: @pimvdb Funny thing is I was... and just after I posted the above comment, I saw that the question was only asked yesterday. Destiny.